# Java launch warning/error while interacting on MacBook Pro touchbar

Tags: java, nstouchbar

I've been developing an application in java, and I've noticted that I get an warning/error while I touching the bar(like dragging up and down volume)..

```
2016-12-20 22:43:18.464 java[1247:84961] *** Assertion failure in -[NSTouch normalizedPosition], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1504.60/AppKit.subproj/NSTouch.m:87
```

Anyone know how I can stop it?